How to Withdraw Assets from BSC Using Safe (Gnosis) SDK?
I have created a vault on Binance Smart Chain (BSC) and now need to write a script to withdraw assets from it using the Safe (formerly Gnosis Safe) SDK. I haven't used the Safe SDK before, so I'm looking for guidance or any existing scripts that can help me achieve this.
Requirements:

Initialize the Safe SDK with my Safe wallet on BSC.
Create and sign a transaction to withdraw BNB or BEP-20 tokens.
Execute the transaction on the Binance Smart Chain.

Questions:
What are the steps to set up the Safe SDK for BSC and withdraw assets?
Are there any ready-made scripts or examples that demonstrate this process?
Any help or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Sure, here are some resources that should help you get started:

Initialize the SDK: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#initialize-signers-providers-and-ethadapter
Create a transaction: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#create-a-transaction
Sign a transaction: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/guides/signatures/transactions
Execute a transaction: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#execute-the-transaction

Hope it helps! Best, Louis
